# How to evaluate acceptance of metropolis-hastings proposal value when using log-likelihood?

Tags: r, mcmc

I'm currently writing a MCMC procedure in R for estimation of Rasch model parameters. To do this I use a metropolis-hastings algorithm in a Gibbs sampler.

In the code below a part of the proposal function for the item parameters is given.

```
y <- rnorm(1,delta[i],sd) #proposal value
# delta[i] is the current delta value from which new proposal is simulated

# calculate log-probability for each person with proposal value
for(p in 1:length(theta)){
  z[i] = log(exp(x[p,i]*(theta[p]-y))/(1 + (exp(x[p,i]*(theta[p]-y)))))
}

# sum log-prob values and add log of f(y)
d.l.p[i] <- sum(z)+log(dnorm(y,0,1)) # d.l.p = delta likelihood proposal

## Is this correct?
if(runif(1)<= exp(d.l.p[i]-d.l.c[i])){ # d.l.c = delta likelihood current value

  delta[i] <- y
  d.l.c[i] <- d.l.p[i]

}
```

My question is whether using `if(runif(1)<= exp(d.l.p[i]-d.l.c[i]))` to determine whether the proposal value should be accepted is correct? I know that in the case of non log-likelihood, you can use `if(runif(1)<= d.l.p[i]/d.l.c[i])` to determine the acceptation of the new value.

Since this is more of a conceptual question than a coding question, I left out the rest of the code. However, if all code is required I'll gladly provide it.

Tnx in advance!
Joost

Comment: Since this is a conceptual statistics question, I'm going to flag this for migration to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com). Its more appropriate for that site; Stack Overflow is more for coding questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've been taking the log of the random uniform, like this:
    if((lpnew-lpold)>log(runif(1)))